# How to permanently "renice" a process on Mac OS X (or iOS, etc)?

Tags: mac-osx, configuration, process, daemon

I use a nice (free) process manager called [ATMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/) for Mac OS X that has a lot of cool hidden features... one of which is being able to click on a running process.. and set the "renice" from +20 (less priority) to -20 (highest priority).

The best part.... it sticks between restarts...  SO you want XYZ to get full attention all the time..  you set it once *and it's done.*..

I want to do the same thing (renice a process) on an iPad running a particular daemon.. But it might as well be a Debian Server, if that retards any flames for posting this question here...  and I don't know how to set a renice permanently.

I can do it once, and it works fine... But the setting is lost on a reboot.  I read somewhere..

> Now, as for permanently resetting the
>   priority of a process, this can't be
>   done directly. You can fake it,
>   however, with a shell script that
>   starts the app and then immediately
>   renice's it. Give that script a
>   ".command" extension and it will be
>   double-clickable in the GUI. Not very
>   elegant, but it gets the job done.

But as it says..  not very elegant, and I dont think this is how ATMonitor does it....

**How do I set a permanent renice level, per executable binary, independent of it's PID, when, how or why it was launched?**

Answer (score 2):

Why not write another daemon that patrols the process table and renices processes based on their image name? This is probably how atMonitor does it.